# running programs via bash like daemons

Tags: linux, bash

Usually I run GUI programs (like libreoffice) just in a terminal, but it means that terminal has to be open while running the app.

How can I let the GUI program continue to run even if I close my terminal?

Comment: `nohup program`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4006/187122.

Comment: Why would you want to launch a gui application in a text terminal if you are not at all interested in the terminal (the output in there)? Sounds to me like you actually are only interested in an easy way to launch applications, but for that you do not need a terminal. Create a keyboard shortcut for the application for example. Or just type the command when the desktop is visible, modern desktop environments like KDE will use a launcher to fire the application. They also offer an explicit launcher, typically ALT-F2.

Comment: While I won't further downvote, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for advice on asking questions, and in particular [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for showing what you've tried, and read over the categories at [this one](http://idownvotedbecau.se/) for instructive examples and explanations.

Comment: Daemons are commonly run with `nohup`, though you can use `trap '...' HUP` to code it right into the script to ignore hangups.

Comment: Unless you're **writing** the program at hand, the question should be asked at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [unix.se], not here; StackOverflow's scope is strictly limited to questions about software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the bash command `nohup`, which disconnects a process from the terminal, so that it keeps running even if the terminal closes. Use it to run 'nautilus' like this:

```
nohup nautilus
```

As you will see, it warns that any stdout from nautilus is saved in a file called nohup.out. If you don't care about the stdout from your GUI app, and don't want to create these nohup.out files, you can redirect stdout to /dev/null. If you do that, nohup saves stderr instead. So you need to redirect both:

```
nohup nautilus >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Also, for reasons I don't understand, this is now a blocking call (ie you don't get your terminal prompt back.) So you need to run this in the background:

```
nohup nautilus >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I've created a Bash function in my .bashrc so that I don't need to type all the above:

```
nh () 
{ 
    nohup "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
}
```

Then I can go:

```
nh nautilus
```

Comment: thanks! I mean, really thank you. i know, it was a stupid question. But it was important for me to get an answer.

Comment: Hey, if you read it. You will understand why it blocks call after reading "Introduction to Linux - A Hands on Guide" chapter 5 "I/O redirection".